# toggle component state angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have developed a component `product-tile`.

This is static HTML.

```
<product-tiles>
  <product-tile (click)="toggleState()"></product-tile>
  <product-tile (click)="toggleState()"></product-tile>
</product-tiles>
```

Clicking on a `product-tile` should expand `tile` and show product information.

I am not able to figure out how can I control the product-tile state based on the `click` event on `product-tile`.

What I tried so far, to add `toggleState` inside `product-tiles` (parent) and emit the event.

but not sure, how this will be listened by child component?

Please correct the understanding.

Robin

Comment: The click logic should be in the child component, not the parent.

Comment: Thanks it worked !

Comment: I'd advise redoing some beginner level Angular tutorials/courses, as this is a basic concept you need to grasp before moving on.